# htaccess rule for subdomain url only

Tags: .htaccess, caching, litespeed

I have a site that can be viewed on admin.mysite.com and www.mysite.com.  The url doesn't change when viewing the site on the subdomain.
The idea is that on the admin.mysite.com subdomain, I want to disable Litespeed cache using this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
CacheDisable public /
CacheDisable private /
</IfModule>
```

However, I need those rules to only work on the subdomain only, not the live domain.
How can I refine this to do that?

Comment: The rules you provided may not help to disable cache on specific subdomain. 
Just to clarify: 
You want admin.mysite.com no cache and www.mysite.com cache enabled?

May I ask your CMS is WordPress? or any LiteSpeedCache plugin supported? or you setup cache by rule set?
These two cases have different method to achieve your needed.

Comment: For rule set case, check this wiki should help: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:cache:no-plugin-joomla